# Problems with scrollview

Tags: android, scroll

I have a activity on my app, that shows a lot of options that can be configurated (textviews and textedits on a linearlayout)

But I have a problem, there are more items that my windows can show, and I can't go down doing down movement with my finger on the screen.

i am trying to do it with scrollview, but i can't my screens appears black and all mny items dissapear

here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">    
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:padding="10px">
<RelativeLayout
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MovileLabel" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="13px"
        android:text="@string/movilephonelabel"/>
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/Movile"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/MovileLabel"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:width="180px"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="5pt"
    android:text="If you want to send SMS invitation" />

<View
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="#808080"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8px"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/EmailLabel" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/emaillabel"
        android:layout_marginTop="13px"/>
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/Email"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/EmailLabel"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:width="180px"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="5pt"
    android:text="If you want to send Email invitation" />

<View
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="#808080"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8px"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PermissionLabel" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/perlabel"
        android:layout_marginTop="13px"/>
    <Spinner 
      android:id="@+id/Permission"
      android:prompt="@string/perlabel"
      android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/PermissionLabel"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:entries="@array/permissions_array"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="#808080"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8px"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/HoursRangeLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hoursrangelabel"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="13px"/>
<RelativeLayout
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/FromLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fromlabel"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="13px"/>
    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/From"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/FromLabel"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/FromLabel"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ToLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tolabel"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/From"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/From"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/To"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/From"
        android:width="70px"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/weekendlabel"
        android:id="@+id/weekendLabel"
        android:layout_marginTop="15px"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/settingsCheckBox"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/weekendLabel"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="5pt"
    android:text="These fields are only necessary for Per Hours permission" />

<View
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="#808080"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8px"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/inviteButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/invite"
        android:width="100px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        android:width="100px"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/inviteButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dip"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I wonder, why you need to do this without scrollview?

Comment: because my app is fully designed without using scrollview, and i am trying to find a way of move my menu up and down without changing my desing and using scrollview..... 



**linear layout haves a property that makes it scrollable????**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

[scroll view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Take a look at that documentation and see if that will help you. There are examples in the link if you need to see some examples.

Comment: i am searching for a way to do something like that without using scrollview... i told in topic...... btw, 
**linear layout haves a property that makes it scrollable????**

Comment: Why do you not want to use scrollview? That just does not make a whole lot of sense, can you please elaborate? We might could help you more if you helped us understand why you do not want to use scrollview.

Comment: i just wanna know if there are a way to do it, and also, i dont want to do changes on my layouts more complex than put a line of code or something, if i can avoid it

Comment: You should only have to wrap your linearly layout with <scrollview> </scrollview> to get it to work.

Comment: Just wrap your layout in a ScrollView. It's a simple `<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"> /* Your layout here */ </ScrollView>`. Why fight it? LinearLayout does not handle scrolling on its own.

Comment: ok, im trying it!!! but my windows appears BLACK, all the items of my windows have turned invisible :S whY ?

Comment: but my windows appears BLACK, all the items of my windows have turned invisible :S whY ?

Comment: You need to make sure that you set the right layout filling parameters. I bet that is your problem now. Post some code and we can help you out better.

Comment: its posted now, on first post

Comment: Try wrap_content instead of fill_parent for your fill parameters in your scrollview tag.

Comment: oh i have an error on the XML.... unbound prefix, on the scrollview i think, wich error is this?

Comment: ok i think its solved, i have to double merge all.... first to merge in a scrollview, and then merge the scrollview in another linearlayout... lol... ¿i will have problems accesing my variables with this double merge solution?

Comment: Move this "xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
" to your scroll view tag, instead of the linear layout tag.

Comment: Undo what you just did and try what i said after you posted. That should fix the problem you were having.

Comment: okay, its solved!!!!   but one question... i will have problems accesing my variables with this merge solution? i will have to change my java code?

Comment: You should not have to change your java code for this to still work. Unless you changed the directory for which your xml was located.

Answer (score 1):

can only contains one child.  You need to put everything on a common layout and then nested it in ScrollView.  Hope it helps